# OpenCV : Using a Trimap image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I found this dog and cat image dataset: [The Oxford-IIIT Pet Dataset](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/pets/). Each image has a pixel level foreground-background segmentation (trimap) image.

Searching the internet, I saw that trimap is an image with three colors (one for the background, one for the foreground and one for the not-classified region), but here the image is all black.

Is it a mistake or is it correct? But above all I want to know if and how you can use it to get, given a normal image, a new image with the cat or dog on a black background.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trimaps look black because they only contain pixels values ranging from 0-2 on a scale of 0-255, where:

- 1 means "pet"
- 2 means "background"
- 3 means "border"

Look at the pixels in text form:

```
identify -verbose Abyssinian_1trimap.png  | more
```

**Output**

```
  Histogram:
     22938: (  1,  1,  1) #010101 gray(1)
    198766: (  2,  2,  2) #020202 gray(2)
     18296: (  3,  3,  3) #030303 gray(3)
```

If you contrast stretch the trimaps, you can see better. I am using the `Abyssinian1` image here:

```
convert Abyssinian_1trimap.png -auto-level trimap.jpg
```

[image]

If you make all the `1` pixels in the trimap white and all the `2` pixels black and all the `3` pixels white and blend that with the actual photo using a `darken` blend, you will get what you want:

```
convert Abyssinian_1.jpg \( Abyssinian_1trimap.png -fill white -opaque "rgb(1,1,1)" -opaque "rgb(3,3,3)" -fill black -opaque "rgb(2,2,2)" \) -compose darken -composite pet.png
```

[image]

If you want the border as well as the pet, do this:

```
convert Abyssinian_1.jpg \( Abyssinian_1trimap.png -fill white -opaque "rgb(1,1,1)" -opaque "rgb(3,3,3)" -fill black -opaque "rgb(2,2,2)" \) -compose darken -composite pet.png
```

[image]

You can also experiment with blurring the mask to soften the edges:

```
convert Abyssinian_1.jpg \( Abyssinian_1trimap.png -fill white -opaque "rgb(1,1,1)" -fill black -opaque "rgb(3,3,3)" -opaque "rgb(2,2,2)" -blur 0x8  \) -compose darken -composite pet.png
```

[image]

Sorry, I did it with **ImageMagick** because I find that easier and it is installed on most Linux distros and available for macOS and Windows. The principles are the same for OpenCV.

Comment: Thanks. How should I change your last command to extend the image even in the border (pixel 3)?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: I'd like the image of the cat was more refined, as if I only want to remove the background from original image. Only the gray part of the trimap (as seen above) should become black in the final image (not gray and white part of the trimap).

Answer (score 1):

Struggled with this for a bit as well until I finally managed to figure it out.To load and display these files in Python you would need this

```
import io
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import PIL
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

with tf.gfile.GFile("Abyssinian_1.png", 'rb') as fid:
    encoded_mask_png = fid.read()
encoded_png_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_mask_png)
mask = PIL.Image.open(encoded_png_io)            
plt.imshow( np.array(mask) / 2 * 255 )
```

Comment: For TF 2 you need to change tf.gfile to tf.io.gfile. For macOS you need to add plt.show(). Otherwise it works :) Thanks for sharing

Comment: `3/2 * 255` bigger than 255.May `(np.array(mask)-1)/2*255`?