# How to generate a Trimap image

Tags: image-processing

I found this dog and cat image dataset:

The Oxford-IIIT Pet Dataset.

Any idea how the pixel level foreground-background segmentation (trimap) image was generated?

I want to use it for my own dataset.

Pixel-level foreground-background segmentation

an image with three colors (one for the background, one for the foreground and one for the not-classified region)

[image]

Comment: Read about Mask-RCNN

Comment: I did something related a while back... https://stackoverflow.com/a/41778637/2836621

Comment: See paragraph 2.1 in the PDF linked on the Oxford website you refer to... https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/publications/2012/parkhi12a/parkhi12a.pdf

Comment: Had the same issue, couldn't figure it out for days but finally managed , posted a reply here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59816307/12744929

Answer (score 1):

Note: Input image is in binary form

```
def generate_trimap(mask_path,eroision_iter=6,dilate_iter=8):
    mask =  mask_path
    mask = cv2.imread(mask,0)
    mask[mask==1] = 255
    d_kernel = np.ones((3,3))
    erode  = cv2.erode(mask,d_kernel,iterations=eroision_iter)
    dilate = cv2.dilate(mask,d_kernel,iterations=dilate_iter)
    unknown1 = cv2.bitwise_xor(erode,mask)
    unknown2 = cv2.bitwise_xor(dilate,mask)
    unknowns = cv2.add(unknown1,unknown2)
    unknowns[unknowns==255]=127
    trimap = cv2.add(mask,unknowns)
    # cv2.imwrite("mask.png",mask)
    # cv2.imwrite("dilate.png",dilate)
    # cv2.imwrite("tri.png",trimap)
    labels = trimap.copy()
    labels[trimap==127]=1 #unknown
    labels[trimap==255]=2 #foreground
    #cv2.imwrite(mask_path,labels)
    return labels
```